# How to allow an Applescript to be exited at any time

Tags: applescript

I am trying to write a script which presses the "w" and "q" keys rapidly for a prolonged period (the purpose is to perform a repetitive activity in a game's practice mode).

I know next to nothing about Applescripts, but I was able to piece together the following which kind of gets the job done:

```
tell application "System Events"
    delay 5
    repeat with i from 1 to 50
        delay 0.25
        keystroke "w"
        delay 0.25
        keystroke "q"
    end repeat
end tell
```

Basically I press "run", alt-tab to the game, and let the script run.

The problem is that I have no way to force-exit the script. I tried the recommendation [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6696176) to use command+option+escape, but I can't manage to click "force quit" and it won't close.

I'm looking at the documentation for [handlers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW7), but I'm not sure exactly what I'm supposed to do. I don't want to close the game application, just stop the script.

Ideally, I could implement some sort of "on key pressed" listener that kills the Applescript.

***edit*** with the suggestion in the comment I now have:

```
use sys : application "System Events"
use framework "Cocoa"

tell application "System Events"
    delay 5
    repeat with i from 1 to 50
        delay 0.25
        keystroke "w"
        delay 0.25
        keystroke "q"
        if modifierKeydown() then exit repeat # Exit on keypresswq
    end repeat
end tell

# Returns true if any of
# { function, control, option, command }
# are depressed; false otherwise
on modifierKeydown()

    set __m to current application's ¬
        NSEvent's modifierFlags() as any

    return (__m > 262143)

end modifierKeydown
```

This raises:

> error "System Events got an error: Can’t continue modifierKeydown." number -1708

Comment: [My answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/317085/266364) to a [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/317055/266364) will hopefully be helpful.  It employs two methods to provide exits from a `repeat` loop: a key press, where that key is a modifier key; or navigating away from the focussed window.  If you’d like me to tailor a version of the script to your specific situation, I’d be happy to do so.

Comment: Hi @CJK thanks very much for sharing this. See my edit to the question with my attempt using your recommendation, and the error that I see.

Comment: You have to use `if my modifierKeydown()` because the parent script owns the handler `modifierKeydown()`, and not *System Events*.

Comment: @CJK Ok thank you! It works. AppleScript does raise an alert saying "the documennt can't be closed when the script is running" but I can press "ok" and the script has successfully stopped. I will mark this as duplicate of the other question.

Comment: @CJK oh, I can't because it's on a different Stack Exchange network. Feel free to post the code as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: The second error that's thrown (about the document not being able to close) is because you'll have, somewhere, instructed your AppleScript to `quit` (which it can't do if it's open in *Script Editor*, but could do if it was saved and running as an application).  However, use `return` instead of `quit` and that should solve that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/317085/266364) to a similar question, here's a semi-tailored solution to your specific situation:

```
    use sys : application "System Events"
    use framework "Cocoa"


    # Bring your game window into focus
    tell application "The Name of Your Game" to activate

    # Might be needed if your game window takes a long time to
    # enter focus.  But if it's already running, it should be instant
    # and this little loop won't be needed.
    # repeat while process "The Name of Your Game" is not frontmost
    # end

    # Get frontmost window of the frontmost application
    set P to a reference to (the first process whose frontmost is true)
    set W to the front window of P


    repeat with i from 1 to 50
        # Terminate loop if the focus changes to another window
        if the front window of P is not equal to W then exit repeat

        delay 0.25
        tell sys to keystroke "w"

        delay 0.25
        tell sys to keystroke "q"

        if modifierKeydown() then exit repeat  # Terminate loop if modifier key is pressed
    end repeat

    return


    # Returns true if any of
    # { function, control, option, command }
    # are depressed; false otherwise
    on modifierKeydown()

        set __m to current application's ¬
            NSEvent's modifierFlags() as any

        return (__m > 262143)

    end modifierKeydown
```